# bind javascript object to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, getter-setter

I'm trying to create a javascript object that keeps track of a form's state. My first stab was a lengthy "procedural" jquery solution, where I loop through each form field, test if it's set to 'All', remove the `active` class, or add it if it's not there. This is a short version:

```
function activeClass() {
  if(this.val() === 'All') {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#content-filter select', context).foreach(function() {
    if(this.val() !== 'All') {
      this.addClass('active');
    }
  });
}
```

We're doing a whole bunch of other things as well, so the code is getting long. The next direction I want to take is to create a separate object that keeps track of the form state and uses event listeners to update the form state as it changes.

```
formState = {
    featured: false,
    all: false,
    category: 'All',
    topics: 'All',
    audience: 'All',
    date: {value: '', min: '', max: '', filter_op: '='},
  };
```

The part that I'm struggling with is how to bind the object to the DOM. My first inclination is to do something like this:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    formState[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
  });
```

The problem here is that the `id` of the select has to match the property. Also, I've been told that the way to do this is use a getter and/or setter method to change those values. I have some understanding of what that means, but where I'm confused is how those get bound to the DOM.

Comment: Why use a separate object to keep track of the state when you can just get the state from the DOM element?

Comment: If you want to keep extra state about the element, you can use jQuery's `.data()` method to associate arbitrary data with a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Life saving suggestion: learn a framework that helps with the data binding, otherwise your code will grow alot and become too difficult to maintain.
[I will leave here some suggestions](http://engineering.paiza.io/entry/2015/03/12/145216).

---

Now, using jQuery to do that...you have 2 main big options:
update the form model at every change (similar to what you have) or just gather all the field data upon a form action (ex: pressing send button).

---

**Option1: Update the model all the time!**

You have to have a good reference (id) to each property in the form so you can create the listeners you need to keep updating your form model as needed.
Similar to what you did:

```
$('#'+fieldId).on('change', function() {
    var myNewValue =  $('#'+fieldId ).getValue();
    updateMyFormModel(fieldId, newValue);
});
```

For every form field you should add a prefix, maybe to indicate where the property is because if you use several forms in the same page and register all the watchers in the same object it can get messy, really fast.

Your form send button should have something like

```
onclick="retrieveMyFormModel()"
```

where you just get your continously updated form model and send it to the server.

**Option2: Gather all the data in the end**

Do nothing until the very end until the user clicks in the send button. 
Go trough all the fields, create your form model and send it.